# CMake adds unwanted files

Tags: cmake

I started a project using CMake and i don't know why, it adds to the build list also files i excluded from build.
My CMakeList.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(MyProj LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE src_files CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    "src/*"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE test_files CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    "test/*"
)

add_library(MyProj SHARED
  cpp.astylerc
  ${src_files}
)

target_compile_definitions(MyProj PRIVATE MYPROJ_LIBRARY)

install(TARGETS MyProj DESTINATION lib)
install(DIRECTORY src/. DESTINATION include/myproj)

add_executable(test
  ${test_files}
)

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC
    "../Dist/include"
)

#find_library(MYPROJ_LIBRARY NAMES MyProj PATHS "../Dist/lib" PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
#target_link_libraries(test LINK_PUBLIC ${MYPROJ_LIBRARY})

find_library(GTEST_LIBRARY NAMES gtest PATHS "/usr/lib" PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
target_link_libraries(test LINK_PUBLIC ${GTEST_LIBRARY})

find_library(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY NAMES gtest_main PATHS "/usr/lib" PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
target_link_libraries(test LINK_PUBLIC ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY})
```

I keep test and sources files in different directories (src and test) and everything works just fine until i try to deploy (install).
When i switch to Debug, i build and i launch deploy, it behaves like it's trying to compile test stuff even if there's no test target specified..

How can i exclude files in the test directory for install target?
I missed something in the CMakeList.txt file (or did something wrong?).

Cheers

Comment: In CMake `install` target unconditionally depends on `all` (default) target. Because your `test` target is built by default, then it is built too when the project is installing. You could pass additional option `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` for the call to `add_executable`, this will disable building the target by default.

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you so much. I didn't find this setting anywhere. Bless u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev said, adding the "EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL" setting to the add_executable() cmake-command for the test target fixed the issue.

More info on: [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).